# Which opcodes where disabled by Satoshi Nakamoto for cve 2010 5137

Tags: script, attack, history, satoshi-nakamoto, opcodes

Lot of opcodes where disabled over the years.

But which opcodes where disabled Satoshi himself and specifically for the any one can spend any coin bug?